# How to use "chrt" and "sched-"-tools in Kubuntu 20.04 and KNOPPIX 9.1?

Tags: bash

For urgent killing of bash's subshells and other processes occuring in a vast number of occurencies, I was about to develop a tool.

Such tool is needed, and does not exist.

See my posts

[bash runs havoc and cannot be stopped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726902/bash-runs-havoc-and-cannot-be-stopped#comment1378783_726902)

[Is there an amergency signal to be sent to bash in order to stop bash forking processes and spawning subshells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727458/is-there-an-amergency-signal-to-be-sent-to-bash-in-order-to-stop-bash-forking-pr#comment1379266_727458)

I intended to use trap on signal SIGURS1.

And the sending of this signal to bind to a key-sequence.

So the action could be triggert fast.

The killing action has to be run with the highest priority, highest real-time priority.

About 20 years ago (in KNOPPIX 5.3.1) I have used "chrt".

Now "chrt" is not available.

This is in contrast to annoumcements that Linux kernel has got additional real-time capabilities.

aptitude shows that it cannot be installed.

Is there a contitunuously updared, trustworthy registry which Linux distrubutions have what missings.

Regards

Anton Wessel

Comment: The real solution is to write shell code that doesn't "run havoc". But I've seen your comments under [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727458/108618) and I understand you want to stop an already working forkbomb without rebooting. In your situation you may try to use `pkill -t …` to send a signal to all processes the controlling terminal of which is the "unlucky" one. But (1) you need to know it first (easy for `ttyN`, but running `tty` in the affected terminal emulator to get `pts/N` may be hard); and (2) there is a way to run processes detached from the controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`chrt` is still available, it’s part of the `util-linux` package.

Comment: Oh, fine. Many thanks for hint that "chrt" is in "utill-linux".  "util-linux" was not installed. Dont know why. After installing, "chrt" now exists. Perhaps some other are now solved, perhaps even "sched..." will exist. Thanks  Regards Anton Wessel.

Comment: It’s not clear to me which `sched` tool you’re looking for, but `schedtool` itself is in the `schedtool` package (which I maintain).